# How does sort(..) influence Big-O notation of my algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

If my algorithm has a complexity of `O(n)` but I use a sorting algorithm inside, which has `O(n log n)`, do I need to count them in?

```
def function(array A):
    A.sort()
    for i in A:
         ...
```

Would this now officially be `O(n)` or `O(n log n)`?

Comment: Yes, in this case it becomes `O(n log n)` or precisely `O(n log n + n)`. If you'd do the sort in each step of your `O(n)` it'd be even worse becoming `O(n^2 log n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall complexity depends on the complexity of `A.sort()`.

- When the complexity of `A.sort()` is `O(1)` (which most likely isn't), then the complexity of your function is `O(n)` (depending on the content of the `for` loop).
- When the complexity of `A.sort()` is `O(n)` (which might be, but usually not), then the complexity of your function is still `O(n)`, since it would be `O(2*n)`.
- When the complexity of `A.sort()` is `O(n log n)`, then the complexity of your function is `O(n log n)`, and your `for` loop is neglectable compared to that.

You can't just ignore the complexity of a code block because you hide it behind a function call and assume it is `O(1)` because *"it is just a function call"*. You have to calculate with the complexity as if you would copy&paste the code of that function in that place.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that's the way how it works but wasn't sure if the notation follows it. Your explanation makes completely sense. Thanks for clarification